# nofile ulimit -n on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, ulimit

```
➜ sudo sysctl -a|grep file

fs.file-max = 2037581
fs.file-nr = 2784   0   2037581

➜ ~ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
2037581

➜ ~ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
2720    0   2037581
```

/etc/security/limits.conf

```
* hard nofile 2037581
* soft nofile 2037581
root hard nofile 2037581
root soft nofile 2037581
```

/etc/pam.d/su

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

/etc/pam.d/common-session

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

then reboot.

but  ulimit -n  got 1024 again.

only can  ulimit -n 4096 as max value

or got error

```
 ulimit: value exceeds hard limit
```

Comment: Did you try setting a minimally changed limit instead?

Answer (score 0):

If u set `root hard nofile 65535` it will only change root users limit.
If you want to change another users limit add that users username for example,

`sharewind hard nofile 65535` 
Or add * for username which will change all users limit. But it is not recommended.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Did you change both soft and hard file limits. If not add the soft file limit too. I used hard limit only as an example

Comment: I have the same experience as @ManulaWaidyanatha

Answer (score 0):

I found that if the service is launched under an upstart init script you must use the stanza limit to control this!

See: http://bryanmarty.com/2012/02/10/setting-nofile-limit-upstart/